# Set CSS variable with quotes and comma from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

I have the following CSS:

```
:root{
  --font-family: "Times", serif;
}

body{
  font-family: var(--font-family);
}
```

I also have a dropdown with the following values:

```
serif
sans-serif
'Montserrat', sans-serif;
'Source Code Pro', monospace;
```

I use this dropdown to set a CSS variable on the body:

```
let root = document.documentElement;

const fontSelect = document.querySelector("#font")

fontSelect.addEventListener("change", e => {
  console.log(fontSelect.value);
  root.style.setProperty('--font-family', fontSelect.value);
});
```

Each time, the correct console log happens, however only `serif` and `sans-serif` are being applied in Google Chrome. How can I make `'Montserrat', sans-serif;` work?

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/3405e40daa7fcc7b17ff8a0e6a205b66

Comment: It should work if you remove the `;` from your values

Comment: @Reyno ah yeah that works, thank you. If you'd like to answer with that I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `;` from your values to make it valid.

```js
let root = document.documentElement;

const fontSelect = document.querySelector("#font")

fontSelect.addEventListener("change", e => {
  console.log(fontSelect.value);
  root.style.setProperty('--font-family', fontSelect.value);
});
```

```css
:root{
  --font-family: "Times", serif;
}

body{
  font-family: var(--font-family);
}
```

```html
<select id="font">
  <option value="serif">Serif</option>
  <option value="sans-serif">Sans serif</option>
  <option value="'Montserrat', sans-serif">Montserrat</option>
  <option value="'Source Code Pro', monospace">Source Code Pro</option>
</select>
```